# asyncData or fetch method with Parameters in NuxtJs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js

I'm working on a nuxtjs project, using asyncData and fetch methods but I need to use parameterize url for get requests and the parameters are present in the data property of vue. How will I use it.

```html
....
data(){
 return {
  param1: "455",
  param2: "xyz",
  products: []
}
},
asyncData(){
    return axio.get(`/api/products?type=${param1}&cat{param2}`).then(response => {
    this products = response.data
 })
}
```

The approach I used here for parameterize url is correct? Please also discuss for fetch methods as well

Comment: Hi, did you checked this one? https://v3.nuxtjs.org/examples/composables/use-async-data

Comment: Thank you for your reply @kissu but it is for vue3, i'm working on vue2

Comment: You tagged your question with a [tag:nuxtjs3] tag, hence why I shared this link. If you want to have the Vue2 version only, you need to use Nuxt2.

Comment: Hi, did the answer helped you somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. `asyncData` hook runs before creating the component, so it doesn't have access to the component instance (because it doesn't exists yet).

`asyncData` could have access to global properties throught the Nuxt context, such as:

- route parameters
- vuex store
- injected properties with plugins

You could use the `fetch` hook instead, which does have access to `this` (the component instance).
The difference is that **it won't block the page render on client navigation**, so you have to handle the loading state with `$fetchState.pending`.

```js
fetch () {
  return axio.get(`/api/products?type=${this.param1}&cat{this.param2}`).then(response => {
    this products = response.data
}
```

Comment: Having a blockable `fetch` is also doable via some middleware hack but yeah, `fetch` is overall-y good/better overall IMO.